# How to create a simple pagination/carousel in divs HTML Angular 2

Tags: angular, pagination, carousel

Hi I have an *ngFor in my template and it creates n number of divs.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of widgets" class="page-content widget-item">
  <div>{{content}} </div>
</div>
```

How can I add a simple pagination on my div's guys? So that my first page will have 10 divs and on click on a button, the page slides and shows the rest of the divs? Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a service like this :

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';

export class PagerService {
getPager(totalItems: number, currentPage: number = 1, pageSize: number = 10) 
{
    // calculate total pages
    let totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);

    let startPage: number, endPage: number;
    if (totalPages <= 10) {
        // less than 10 total pages so show all
        startPage = 1;
        endPage = totalPages;
    } else {
        // more than 10 total pages so calculate start and end pages
        if (currentPage <= 6) {
            startPage = 1;
            endPage = 10;
        } else if (currentPage + 4 >= totalPages) {
            startPage = totalPages - 9;
            endPage = totalPages;
        } else {
            startPage = currentPage - 5;
            endPage = currentPage + 4;
        }
    }

    // calculate start and end item indexes
    let startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
    let endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);

    // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
    let pages = _.range(startPage, endPage + 1);

    // return object with all pager properties required by the view
    return {
        totalItems: totalItems,
        currentPage: currentPage,
        pageSize: pageSize,
        totalPages: totalPages,
        startPage: startPage,
        endPage: endPage,
        startIndex: startIndex,
        endIndex: endIndex,
        pages: pages
    };
   }
}
```

And change your component like below :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

import * as _ from 'underscore';

import { PagerService } from './_services/index'

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'app',
   templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
 })

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private http: Http, private pagerService: PagerService) { }

// array of all items to be paged
private allItems: any[];

// pager object
pager: any = {};

// paged items
pagedItems: any[];

ngOnInit() {
    // get dummy data
    this.http.get('./dummy-data.json')
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            // set items to json response
            this.allItems = data;

            // initialize to page 1
            this.setPage(1);
        });
}

setPage(page: number) {
    if (page < 1 || page > this.pager.totalPages) {
        return;
    }

    // get pager object from service
    this.pager = this.pagerService.getPager(this.allItems.length, page);

    // get current page of items
    this.pagedItems = this.allItems.slice(this.pager.startIndex, this.pager.endIndex + 1);
}
}
```

and your HTML should be something like this :

```
<div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Angular 2 - Pagination Example with logic like Google</h1>

        <!-- items being paged -->
        <div *ngFor="let item of pagedItems">{{item.name}}</div>

        <!-- pager -->
        <ul *ngIf="pager.pages && pager.pages.length" class="pagination">
            <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
                <a (click)="setPage(1)">First</a>
            </li>
            <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
                <a (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage - 1)">Previous</a>
            </li>
            <li *ngFor="let page of pager.pages" [ngClass]="{active:pager.currentPage === page}">
                <a (click)="setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
            </li>
            <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
                <a (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage + 1)">Next</a>
            </li>
            <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
                <a (click)="setPage(pager.totalPages)">Last</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

you can see an example here :

https://plnkr.co/edit/vPXf2U?p=preview

Comment: Hi Emad, what if i just dont want to use bootstrap.Just a dot button based on the number of div?

Comment: In this example, bootstrap only used for styling, if your don't use it, the pagination still works fine, but of course you need to style it yourself from scratch

Answer (score 1):

This link may benefits your need

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/23/angular-2-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google

Comment: Actually am not looking for pagination. Looking for a slider actually